# Convert xml document to json

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My code is as follows.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestStore1.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
    {
        str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(str);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
    }
}
```

It is giving the error at the line of `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);`

> *Error - Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' does not contain a definition for 'SerializeXmlNode'*

Comment: Which version of Json.NET are you using?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json version 5.0.8.16617

Comment: Hmm. What sort of project is this? If you're using the PCL version of Json.NET, that could explain it...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dotnet core, install the `Newtonsoft.Json` package via nuget.